# Is there an equivalent of requeir/sprockets in nodejs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I have experience in ruby on rails and have been using middleman and sprockets to minify and merge javascript. Is there an equivalent in nodejs?

Comment: Yes, `grunt` and `broccoli`.

Comment: I have found one for sass that doesn't requier grunt, something similair would be great.